# The Specifics of Meta-Data

Tags: metadata

How exactly is meta-data organized within the files themselves?  Are there generic categories setup within the data structure of a .wav, or can they be assigned manually, i.e. differently by each program that makes use of the files?

The reason for the question is that I'm currently embedding meta-data via PT, but I do have plans (eventually) to buy soundminer.  I don't want to do all of this embedding now, only to turn around in 8 or 12 months time and have to re-do the entire thing because soundminer uses its own categorization system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have already seen this but in case you haven't, there are <strike>two</strike> three excellent posts on the subject on Tim Prebble's website:

[You and your Metadata...](http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/you-and-your-metadata)

[Metadata support in Sound Library Apps](http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/metadata-support-in-sound-library-apps)

+

[Metadata: Additional Fields?](http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/metadata-additional-fields)

Comment: @georgi.m, I'm still working my way through Mr.P's posts.  There're rather a lot of them.  Thanks.