# Sound Library Management

Tags: effects, library

Hi there,

I hope someone can help.

I have been kindly given a sound effects library containing 20,000 plus sounds.

The thing is, the sounds are indexed by reference of numbers; rather than naming each sound.

I have made enquiries about how best to access these sounds without having to actually play each sound effect to find out what they are.

It has been mentioned that there is some sort of database software out there that would organise and name the individual sound effects allowing easy access to each sound, but no one seems to recall the name of the software.

Can any body help with any pointers please.

Many thanks in advance.

Asteriks

Comment: Well for starters, who created the library? The person that gave  it to you? If not, will the original owner still be using the (commercial) library themselves? 
If so, it might seem a very kind gesture of them to 'give' you a sound library with 20K sounds, but unfortunately it is illegal to use such a library. Could you elaborate on the specifics of this 'transaction'?

Comment: .....'elaborating on the specifics of this transaction'..... 

I was given a computer with a hard-drive that has the files on it, many recorded by an associate.
 
I'm fully aware of the 'legalities' surrounding the use of other peoples 'sounds', and feel not the need to be drawn into any discussion that seems to imply some possible pre-conceived; wrong doing.

Thanking you Arnoud Traa for taking the time to respond, even though it contributed in no way to address the question posed in my query.

Asteriks

Answer (score 1):

[The Specifics of Meta-Data](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/the-specifics-of-meta-data)

Comment: Thank you spoons r better, for helpful response to my query.

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been discussed before.  Search the site and you should find discussions about various database apps.

Comment: Thank you Chuck Russom, for helpful response to my query.